# run similar query with different params

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have order and line table.

An order can have one or more lines.
A line references product (bought product), date_at (you can think of a ticket. A date which you can use this ticket)

```
create table o (
 id integer NOT NULL
);


CREATE TABLE line (
    id integer NOT NULL,
    order_id integer NOT NULL,
    product_id integer NOT NULL,
    date_at date
  );
```

I'm looking for how many `bookings/reservations` I have for each date. 
I can get list of `(date_at, count)` for each date

```
select date(t3.date_at), count(*)
from (
    select t1.id, date(t2.date_at) as date_at, count(*)
    from o t1
        inner join line t2 on t1.id = t2.order_id
    group by t1.id, date(t2.date_at)) t3
group by date(t3.date_at);
```

Now I want the results for each product.

i.e. I want for each product_id, I'd like to get the list of `(date, count)` for orders that contains the product (an order where at least one line contains `product_id`) .

I could run the following query in a loop with different `{product_id}` but I guess there could be a better way

```
select date(t3.date_at), count(*)
from (
    select t1.id, date(t2.date_at) as date_at, count(*)
    from o t1
        inner join line t2 on t1.id = t2.order_id
    where t2.product_id={product_id}
    group by t1.id, date(t2.date_at)) t3
group by date(t3.date_at);
```

I'm using postgres.

Comment: Why would you put the order date in the `line` table?  And, tag your question with the database you are using.

Comment: you shouldn't group by the order id to get the number of orders per date

Comment: @GordonLinoff I edited the op, it's not order date, it's the date associated with the product.

Comment: @McNets: postgres

Answer (score 2):

Your query seems too complicated.  I think this does what you want:

```
select product_id, date(date_at), count(*) as cnt
from line l
group by product_id, date(date_at)
order by product_id, date(date_at);
```

If a product can appear on multiple lines within an order, then use:

```
select product_id, date(date_at), count(distinct order_id) as cnt
from line l
group by product_id, date(date_at)
order by product_id, date(date_at);
```

You don't even need to `join` back to `orders`.  I will point out, though, that having the date in `orders` makes more sense (to me) than having it in `lines`.

Comment: My bad, I had to explain what date_at means.. I edited the op to explain it. It's the product's attribute not the order's. The date_at specifies which date you can use the product. It's the `reserved date`.